# Expression of type Messaging.SingleEmailMessage has no member named SetTemplateId

Tags: apex

I found several examples online that do this, but I am getting the error `Compilation error: Expression of type Messaging.SingleEmailMessage has no member named SetTemplateId  Task_TriggerController.cls  /Client/src/classes line 95 Force.com` compilation problem.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
EmailTemplate template = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = '1st Email' Limit 1];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
sendTo.add(mapTaskToEmail.Get(tsk.Id));
mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
mail.setReplyTo(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
mail.setSenderDisplayName(UserInfo.getFirstName() + ' ' + UserInfo.getLastName());
mail.setSubject('CoreDial - Introduction & Follow-Up');
/*This Works
String body = 'This is a test message';
*/

/*This does not work
mail.SetTemplateId = template.Id;  /*Line 95*/
mail.setTargetObjectId = mapLeadIdToLead.Get(Tsk.WhoId).id;
*/
```

Why can I not use a template in my trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling them as methods, not assigning to them as properties e.g.

```
mail.SetTemplateId(template.Id); // Not mail.SetTemplateId = template.Id
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  I looked at it for 15 minutes and didn't see that.  Hate when that happens.